# Как в стандартном эмуляторе Google установить Play market?

Tags: android

Как в стандартном эмуляторе Google установить Play market? Что бы была возможность синхронизировать контакты и устанавливать приложения из Play market?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На счет стандартного эмулятора не знаю, но в [genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) можно это сделать.

[Установка сервисов гугл...](http://xn----7sbmatugdkfphym2m9a.xn--p1ai/genymotion-ustanovka-prilozhenij.html)

Нужно установить в эмулятор **Genymotion ARM Translation** после этого уже **Google Apps**

В статье все подробно описано.

Comment: В genymotion без проблем,  а вот как в стандартном?

Comment: Ели хотите заморочиться то почитайте [статью на хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/134509/), правда старовата она.

Answer (score 1):

Надо создать эмулятор с поддержкой *Google Services* - там по-моему будет эмулятор.

На стандартный эмулятор без поддержки *Google Services* невозможно установить маркет плей - это точно.

Answer (score 0):

1. Рут
2. Рекавери
3. Гаппсы
4. ???
5. PROFIT!